# Python & Numpy - create dynamic, arbitrary subsets of ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I am looking for a general way to do this:

```
raw_data = np.array(somedata)   
filterColumn1 = raw_data[:,1]
filterColumn2 = raw_data[:,3]
cartesian_product = itertools.product(np.unique(filterColumn1), np.unique(filterColumn2))
for val1, val2 in cartesian_product:
    fixed_mask = (filterColumn1 == val1) & (filterColumn2 == val2)
    subset = raw_data[fixed_mask]
```

I want to be able to use any amount of filterColumns. So what I want is this:

```
filterColumns = [filterColumn1, filterColumn2, ...]
uniqueValues = map(np.unique, filterColumns)
cartesian_product = itertools.product(*uniqueValues)
for combination in cartesian_product:
    variable_mask = ????
    subset = raw_data[variable_mask]
```

Is there a simple syntax to do what I want? Otherwise, should I try a different approach?

**Edit: This seems to be working**

```
cartesian_product = itertools.product(*uniqueValues)
for combination in cartesian_product:

    variable_mask = True
    for idx, fc in enumerate(filterColumns):
        variable_mask &= (fc == combination[idx])

    subset = raw_data[variable_mask]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use numpy.all and index broadcasting for this

```
filter_matrix = np.array(filterColumns)
combination_array = np.array(combination)
bool_matrix = filter_matrix == combination_array[newaxis, :]   #not sure of the newaxis position
subset = raw_data[bool_matrix]
```

There are however simpler ways of doing the same thing if your filters are within the matrix, notably through `numpy argsort` and `numpy roll` over an axis. First you roll axes until your axes until you've ordered your filters as first columns, then you sort on them and slice the array vertically to get the rest of the matrix.

In general if an for loop can be avoided in Python, better avoid it.

**Update:**

Here is the full code without a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np

# select filtering indexes
filter_indexes = [1, 3]
# generate the test data
raw_data = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(50,5))


# create a column that we would use for indexing
index_columns = raw_data[:, filter_indexes]

# sort the index columns by lexigraphic order over all the indexing columns
argsorts = np.lexsort(index_columns.T)

# sort both the index and the data column
sorted_index = index_columns[argsorts, :]
sorted_data = raw_data[argsorts, :]

# in each indexing column, find if number in row and row-1 are identical
# then group to check if all numbers in corresponding positions in row and row-1 are identical
autocorrelation = np.all(sorted_index[1:, :] == sorted_index[:-1, :], axis=1)

# find out the breakpoints: these are the positions where row and row-1 are not identical
breakpoints = np.nonzero(np.logical_not(autocorrelation))[0]+1

# finally find the desired subsets 
subsets = np.split(sorted_data, breakpoints)
```

An alternative implementation would be to transform the indexing matrix into a string matrix, sum row-wise, get an argsort over the now unique indexing column and split as above.

For conveniece, it might be more interesting to first roll the indexing matrix until they are all in the beginning of the matrix, so that the sorting done above is clear.

Comment: I would love to accept your answer but not everybody can rotate n-dimensional matrices in their head. ;) In other words, I'm not sure how to implement this solution for my problem. I dug into the argsort and rollaxis docs a bit but how to apply them to get subsets is beyond me. Luckily my data isn't too big so the loop's just fine, though I fully agree with your statement that it's better to avoid loops when possible.

Comment: Please se the update. Actually it was the lexsort I was thinking about, not the argsot, which both provide the sorting indexes array, just on several single element of an axis versus a several elements of an axis :D

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed update! I follow your logic now and learned a better way of thinking about data manipulation in numpy. Is the method you use to get the autocorrelation and breakpoints fairly standard? It seems it would be difficult for a novice to understand what you're doing in the code without the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
variable_mask = np.ones_like(filterColumns[0])     # select all rows initially
for column, val in zip(filterColumns, combination):
    variable_mask &= (column == val)
subset = raw_data[variable_mask]
```